# Space character in python that won't be interpreted by bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, ascii

I have a Python script `script.py` which I am using to generate the command line argument to another script exactly like so:

`./main $(./script.py)`

The output of `script.py` may contain spaces (e.g. `foo bar`) which are being unintentionally interpreted by the shell. I want the argument to `./main` to be the single string `"foo bar"`. Of course I can solve this problem if I quote the argument to `./main`, like this:

`./main "$(./script.py)"`

But I can't and don't want to do that. (The reason is because `./main` is being called without quotes from another script which I don't have control to edit.)

Is there an alternative representation of the `space` character that my Python script can use, and that bash won't interpret?

Comment: `But I can't and don't want to do that.` why?

Comment: @LieRyan I added an explanation in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to have `./script.py` output a non-breaking space (U+00a0) instead of a regular space, which `bash` will not use for word-splitting. However, I would file a bug report to have the script that calls `main` add quotes to its argument. Whether this works depends on how `main` reacts to getting a string that consists of a two-byte UTF-8 sequence representing U+00a0 rather than a single space character.

A sample `script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print u'foo\xa0bar'.encode('utf8')
```

A sample script `a.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
main () {
    echo $#
}
main $(script.py)
```

And finally, a demonstration that `main` gets 1 argument from the output of `script.py`:

```
$ bash a.bash
1
```

Comment: Actually I need `chr(0x20) = ' '` because this is for a byte-wise interpreted string in a C program. Essentially I want the value `\x20` but every way I tried, the shell is interpreting the space.

Comment: Yes; if you have to use ASCII 20, you're going to have to modify (or have some one modify for you) the script that calls `main`. You can't disable word-splitting from outside the shell that runs the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your python script to escape the spaces in the output if you cannot quote the calling code.

See this code snippet:

```
arg1() { echo "$1"; }
arg1 abc def
abc

arg1 abc\ def
abc def
```

So as you can see if you output `abc\ def` instead of `abc def` from python code it will be considered single argument.

Comment: I don't think that works; try `set -- $(printf foo\ bar); echo "[$1]"`; quoting `foo\ bar` doesn't help either - am I missing something?

Comment: Yes - in the printf, you have to have two backslashes to print one. Escape the escape character.

Comment: @mklement0: Did my enclosed example not work for you? printf is interpreted differently.

Comment: @mpez0: You're right, I should have escaped, but it still doesn't work with two backslashes: `$1` will end up `foo\ `).

Comment: @anubhava: Your example works, but a problem arises when _command substitution_ comes into play: if the command outputs a literal `\ `, the shell will _not_ interpret it as a an escaped space; try this revised example: `set -- $(echo 'foo\ bar'); echo "[$1]"`

Comment: @anubhava: -1: `arg1 abc\ def` doesn't show how to do `./main $(./script.py)`. If you think it should work then provide an example something like: `arg1 $(your command here)`. @mklement0 established that neither `printf foo\\ bar` nor `echo 'foo\ bar'` work. *"output abc\ def"* fails -- it shows foo\

Comment: Yes I just came back and see your point. I guess command substitution makes it difficult since string is interpreted by shell twice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- you have control over `./main` and that it is a shell script
- the *entire* output from the Python script is to be interpreted as a single parameter

simply use `$*` rather than `$1` inside `./main`

Comment: `./main` is a C program which I don't have control over.

Comment: @jp24: Got it. I suggest you add this information to your question. I'll delete my answer then.

Comment: @mklemnt0 No problem. I suggest you leave your answer, I did learn about `$*` which I wasn't familiar with before.